# Как вывести из mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, вывожу из mysql столбец с цифрами, как теперь мне обратиться к 2 строке этого столбца? Что бы произвести какие то математические действия например сложить первую строку столбца со второй.. 
$row['exp_cnt'][1] - мне выводит второй символ из каждой строки..((

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
print_r($row['exp_cnt']);
}
```

Comment: складывать надо прямо SQLзапросе, и получать сразу готовый результат

Comment: Ну вот у вас же цикл. на втором проходе цикла у вас вторая запись. значит на первом надо где то запомнить значение, а на втором уже складывать. Хотя, конечно, Ипатьев прав, данные надо прямо в SQL собирать в том виде, в каком они нужны, а в php это делать не рекомендуется. это медленнее и часто не удобно

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, сделать массив, куда записывать результаты. А потом считать в том цикле, или прямо в этом цикле

ну а вообще - лучше прямо в sql запросе производить такие операции, sql работает быстрее чем php.

```
$res = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $res[] = $row['exp_cnt'];
}

$res - будет хранить все результаты выборки
```

Comment: Добрый день, помогите с запросом пожалуйста.
есть mysql таблица:
id|name|num
1|q|1000
2|w|800
3|e|600
4|r|700
Задача, при селекте сделать операцию над num в итоге получить столбец со значениями.
1000-800=200
800-600=200
600-700=-100

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if ($i > 2) { break; }
    if ($i == 2) {
        $second_row = $row['exp_cnt'];
        echo $second_row;
    }
$i++;
}
```